# Are there any Keyboard Shortcuts to Shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, shortcut-keys

Are there any Keyboard Shortcuts to Shutdown? (e.g. in Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No, but assuming you're using 11.10, one can easily be added by going to:

1. System Settings
2. Keyboard
3. Shortcuts tab
4. Custom Shortcuts
5. Then the little <kbd>+</kbd> icon.

You can give it the name "Shutdown", and the command.  Try the command below:

```
gnome-session-quit --power-off --force
```

, then apply whatever keyboard shortcut you want to it.

Comment: It's worth noting that in GNOME 3.34, you need to go to Devices in the GNOME Settings application, then Keyboard Shortcuts from there. I'm no longer on Ubuntu but those are the steps for the generic GNOME Settings app.

Comment: If you don't want to skip shutdown dialog box, remove `--force` option:
`gnome-session-quit --power-off`

Answer (score 29):

**Yes** there is shortcut to shutdown *(not a keyboard one)*.

Shortly pressing and releasing the **power button** will call the shutdown dialogue box.

Comment: not on my thinkpad... whad does it depend on?

Comment: haha. Good point there.

Comment: Interesting, this approach works. But it's bugged. The dialog "Shut system down?" appears ... but you can't navigate or confirm with the keyboard.  One has to set focus and confirm by mouse clicks.

Comment: GOLD! the simplest and most obvious of all... and i never even thought about trying that

Answer (score 18):

You can try this steps as well:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.
2. The file menu will get displayed in the top.
3. Use the <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> key in your keyboad and go to  extreme right (Pressing <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> might also work and be much faster).
4. Select the shutdown in from the menu and hit enter.

Comment: This is not a shortcut, just keyboard navigation through menu.

Answer (score 5):

The command in [Thomas Boxley's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/91514/22949) works pretty well, but you may want to instead use a command that shuts down and powers off the machine, **without any warning dialog**.

If you want that, you can use this command:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

[Making a shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/a/91514/22949) for the above command instead provides an instant "quick power off."

Answer (score 4):

This probably not a shortcut, but you dont need a mouse to perform it:
Press alt.

In the hud that appears, start typing shut down "Device>Shut Down" should most likely be the first option, press enter.

This opens the shut down dialog box. You can now choose to shut down or restart using arrow keys and then press enter.

It seems a lot, but its really just around 10 key strokes.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 13.04, you can set a keyboard shortcut to this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dbus-send --print-reply --dest="org.gnome.Shell" /org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog.Open uint32:2 uint32:0 uint32:60 array:objpath:/org/gnome/SessionManager/EndSessionDialog
```

This would bring up the shutdown dialog.