# Keyboard shortcut to shutdown?

Tags: shutdown

I came across [Why do we need to be root in terminal for shutdown and restart?](https://askubuntu.com/q/361988/248158) and the accepted answer has an explanation indicating that clicking on "Shutdown" in Ubuntu's dropdown menu triggers this command:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown
```

I also saw [Are there any Keyboard Shortcuts to Shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/a/187372/248158) which suggested this code:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

The two codes differ. (Also, I don't know why `--system` comes twice in second code.) Which code is appropriate for 13.10? Or is there a new code to be used?

Then I can make keyboard shortcut of this command to shutdown my computer from the keyboard instead of having to use the mouse to click on "cogwheel", "shutdown".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can assign a specific, non-used key-combination as a shortcut to shut-down. To assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (or any other key combination) as the shortcut, go to **System settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom shortcut** and then add a new shortcut.

The command should be

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

I am not pretty sure why you have `--system` twice in the command, but a single one works on Ubuntu 13.10(have tested, confirmed to work).