# Confirm shutdown with Zenity?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shutdown, zenity

I got [this command](https://askubuntu.com/a/423128/248158) which enables me to shutdown Ubuntu 13.10 directly from the keyboard (without needing to open a terminal and running something like `sudo shutdown -h now`):

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

I have bound this command to a shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> and it works.

However, I want to know if I can get a **Zenity** window which will run the above shutdown command if I type `y` as a response; but if I press `n` the Zenity window should close and I can continue with my session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following script,

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

zenity --question --text="Are you sure, proceed to shutdown?"
if [ $? = 0 ]; then
    dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop

else
    exit
fi
```

**Usage**

save the script as `shutdown.sh`. Give it execution permission as,

```
chmod +x shutdown.sh
```

To shutdown use,

```
./shutdown.sh
```

You will get the following notice from `zenity`

[image]

**keyboard shortcut**

you can set custom keyboard shortcut for the script from **System settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts >> Custom shortcut** In the field `command` use,

```
/path/to/shutdown.sh
```

**From terminal**

Create a folder `bin` in your home. check if it is in your `PATH`,

```
echo $PATH
```

If you can not see it in your path, make it available in path. You can use following commands in your terminal for this,

```bsh
cd
mkdir bin
echo -e "\nexport PATH=\$HOME/bin:\$PATH" | tee -a ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

Put `shutdown.sh` in `bin` folder. Then you will be able to access the executable from terminal as,

```
shutdown.sh
```

Comment: Did you test the script ? Yes = shutdown, No = No.

Comment: @NikTh yes I tested it.

Comment: Ha, I didn't comment to you \sourvac\ , but I forgot to mention the user @DKBose ;) . Nice addition by the way (on how to).

Comment: The `bin/` "exportation" included already in `.profile`

Comment: @NikTh Yes you are correct. I just checked it. Thanks. I edited accordingly.