# Create a keyboard shortcut to (force) shutdown in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, shutdown, 17.10

I'm looking for a way to force shutdown the system using a single keyboard shortcut, nothing else, in [ubuntu17.10](/questions/tagged/ubuntu17.10) using GNOME. I tried adding a keyboard shortcut using the command found here : [Are there any Keyboard Shortcuts to Shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91501/are-there-any-keyboard-shortcuts-to-shutdown)
which is

`gnome-session-quit --power-off --force`

The `--force` option doesn't seem to be working, though. The shortcut opens the Power Off dialog with the usual cancel, restart and power off options. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `sudo shutdown now` works.

Comment: I tried `sudo shutdown now` and it didn't work. Strangely enough, I then tried `shutdown now` and now it does...